# Off topic: How can I measure the exact time differences (offsets) between two machine?

Tags: support, off-topic

My question is following:

**How can I measure the exact time differences (offsets) between two machine?**

How can the time differences between two Linux machine be measured accurately? I heard that 'Ping' gives RTT with the association of OS influences therefore not accurate in nanosecond level? If so, what else there have to measure the time difference (offsets) between two machines in Linux based system or Raspi?

Sadly Moderator put it on-hold even after some important developments. He says, *This question is off topic here, as it is about a protocol above OSI layer 4 (NTP). It may be on topic on Server Fault or Super User. – Teun Vink*♦

Actually, on that question, many contributors talked about NTP, which can be handy to get my objectives. But I did not ask anything about NTP which resides in the Application layer (as up of layer 4 of OSI that moderator indicates). Interestingly PTP also is a potential daemon to utilize reside in Datalink Layer (Layer 2). So what's the point?

Do the sites want to delete my question?

Answer (score 2):

Time keeping is something the operating system does, it's not part of the network layers. Questions about operating systems like linux are off topic here. Your question is really not suited here, but can be on topic on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com.

Your argument that a protocol uses networking is irrelevant, that would make any question about any protocol using IP on topic here, which isn't the case.

You're free to delete your own question if you feel the need.

Comment: Finding out time differences (offsets) between two machines must relate to the networks that the system is going to use. So, if you use wifi (that I aimed at) you have to aware of the TSF which is a time keeping register in the network layer. So, any OS geek who may haven't clear idea about networking is no use to put any meaningful comments.
However, my goal is to get the idea, where from does it gets is not an issue. So, How can I transfer the whole thread into the other sites you directed, please?

Comment: Again: the fact that something uses a network does not automatically make the question on topic here. Please read the help center documentation to see what's on topic here. I'll try to transfer the question to [sf], but it's up to them to decide if it's on topic here.